# C# huge memory usage when sending file, System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, exception, memory, tcp, stream

I am working at a program that sends/receives files over the network using the `TCP`. 
The program sends multiple files, so the stream is not close until the user quits the program.

The problem that i am facing is that, when i am sending a 700mb file, my server program private memory grows to 700,000 K and cripples my computer performance badly. And when trying to send another 700mb file the server throws an `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong, or not doing ?

Server-side code:

```
   using (   FileStream fs = new FileStream("dracula.avi", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))                            
  {                                                        
   byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
   int remaining = data.Length;
   int offset = 0;

   strWriter.WriteLine("Content-Length: " + data.Length);
   strWriter.Flush();

   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   while (remaining > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            int read = fs.Read(data, offset, remaining);
            remaining -= read;
            offset += read;

        }

   fs.Flush();
   fs.Close();
 }   

  strm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  strm.Flush();
  GC.Collect();
```

Comment: don't declare an array like `byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];`. read data in smaller chucks and send them in a loop

Comment: Thank you, that is what i am going to do.

Answer (score 4):

You're currently reading the whole file into memory, even though you only want to copy it to another stream. Don't do that. Just iterate a chunk at a time: read a chunk, write a chunk, read a chunk, write a chunk, etc. If you're using .NET 4, you can use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) for that purpose.

Comment: I also thought that my work, but i thought that there my bee a method to free the memory. Thank you again, Jon.

Comment: Is there a safe number of bytes i can read and write? i am currently using 4096 and it seams very very slow ?

Comment: @Spreadzz: I would personally use 32K instead of 4K, but even with 4K it shouldn't be "very very slow". You should post the code you've tried (edit your question). Also, if you've still got the `Thread.Sleep` call in (it's not clear why that was there to start with) that would obviously be a bad idea...

Comment: I got it working, it was the Thread.Sleep , i used it because in some cases it helped me take the load off the cpu, but now i think it`s not a good ideea.

Comment: Never ever never ever use Thread.Sleep in your code.  It means something else is wrong when you think you need it.  It's great for debugging and testing - but that's usually it.

Answer (score 3):

You're buffering your reads, but not your writes. The program is doing exactly what you're telling it to -- allocating a gigantic chunk or memory and filling it all before ever sending a single byte.

A much better approach is to read a small chunk from the file (for the sake of argument, 4096 bytes) and then write the chunk to the output stream. By doing this, you'll only use 4096 bytes per connection which is much more scalable.

Comment: Is there a safe number of bytes that i read and write ? It seams like reading and writing 4096 is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Better send the data chunks as soon as you read them. I didn't test the code, but it should be similar to something like;

```
   var bufferLenght = 1024;
   byte[] buffer;

   while (remaining > 0)
   {
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = fs.Read(buffer, offset, bufferLenght);
            remaining -= len;
            offset += len;    
            strm.Write(buffer, 0, len);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

An OOM condition generally occurs when you are either running out of system memory, or in a 32 bit process you are out of address space(2000MB).

You say it can successfully copy one but not two?  Is that two concurrently or consecutively?  What is your threading model?  Also, the example is a snippet, you seem to have a StreamWriter and a Stream for writing, are these objects going away?

Be careful with GC.Collect.  Microsoft doesn't recommend explicit calls because if you don't use it correctly it can cause objects to stay alive longer than needed.  This is because when you do a GC.Collect, you are promoting objects to a higher generation.  In my experience it is best to make sure you are releasing objects and let the framework decide what/when to GC.Collect.

I would get familiar with WinDBG+SOS, this allows you to look at the objects on the heap.

Try this:

1. Startup WinDBG and attach to your process
2. Type ".loadby sos clr" if using 4.0, otherwise type ".loadby sos mscorwks"
3. Press F5 to continue
4. Copy one file, wait for it to complete
5. Press CTRL+BREAK
6. Type "!dumpheap -stat", look at the results, look for objects that should be gone
7. For-Each object that should be gone, grab the MT value
8. Type "!dumpheap -mt {0}" replacing {0} with the value from step above
9. This is a list of instances, grab one of the objects addresses
10. Type "!gcroot {0}" replacing {0} with the objects address

This should tell you what is rooting the objects, you then need to find out how to unroot, e.g. null objects that aren't needed.

Comment: I tried two files consecutively. It was because i loaded the whole stream in the byte[] instead of little chunks. I fix it. But also thank you i will definitely give WinDBG a try.